# Android: Not able to createFile on external storage

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a file on external storage but android is throwing error while doing that.

I have already gone through many questions asked on stackoverflow but still unable to find the problem.

I have provided permissions in manifest file.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jewelmahal.jewellerapp">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".signup.CompanyDetailsSignupActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_signup"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".signup.UploadTinActivity"
            android:label="@string/upload_tin_title"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**AsyncTask**

```
private class SaveImageToSD extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Integer, String> {
    private Bitmap tinImageBitmap;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Nothing yet
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        tinImageBitmap = bitmaps[0];
        tinImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return null; //Cannot write to Strorage
        }

        Log.d("EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "AVAILABLE FOR READ/WRITE");

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "JewelMahal");
        Log.d("Can Write", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite() + "");
        if (!file.mkdirs() && !file.isDirectory()) {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Directory not created");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Directory created");
        }

        File destination = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + TIN_FILE_PREFIX + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        Log.d("Location:", destination.getAbsolutePath());
        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("FileNotFound", "dsda");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("IOException", "dsda");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (tinImagePath=destination.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String tinPath) {
        tinPreview.setImageBitmap(tinImageBitmap);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
02-10 09:14:52.206 29864-32486/? W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-10 09:14:52.215 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
02-10 09:14:52.216 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at com.jewelmahal.jewellerapp.signup.UploadTinActivity$SaveImageToSD.doInBackground(UploadTinActivity.java:65)
02-10 09:14:52.216 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at com.jewelmahal.jewellerapp.signup.UploadTinActivity$SaveImageToSD.doInBackground(UploadTinActivity.java:33)
02-10 09:14:52.216 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
02-10 09:14:52.216 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-10 09:14:52.216 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
02-10 09:14:52.216 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
02-10 09:14:52.216 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
02-10 09:14:52.216 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-10 09:14:52.217 29864-32486/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-10 09:14:52.220 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-10 09:14:52.220 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
02-10 09:14:52.220 29864-32486/? W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
02-10 09:14:52.220 29864-32486/? W/System.err:  ... 8 more
```

Comment: First you need to create the directory before you create your file. Use mkdir/mkdirs function

Comment: Please look closely at my code, I'm already doing that.

Comment: @user2899951 I was able to create the file without a problem using your code. Could you paste your whole Manifest and AsyncTask?

Comment: @Evin1_ I have added the AndroidManifest.xml and AsyncTask to save image on SD.

Comment: @user2899951 Yeap, again, no errors when running your code. http://i.imgur.com/0wDSY7d.png

Comment: @user2899951 Might have something to do with your TIN_FILE_PREFIX

Comment: @Evin1_ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite() is giving false for me. What do you mean by TIN_FILE_PREFIX is having something to do with it?

Comment: @user2899951 Are you working with an Emulator? If so which one?

Comment: @Evin1_  Tried on Emulator and Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1. Emulator settings are Nexus 5 API 23 x86 with Android 6.0.  Having the same error on Emulator and Nexus 5 phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant permissions explicitly for it to work on Marshmallow.

Either change the target to Lollipop in your build.gradle or request for permission.

You can also go to settings, apps. Your app, and grant permission there manually.

Here is a nice guide to request permission:

https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-marshmallow-permissions.html